# Search in sub sub sub array

Tags: mongodb

Example document from database

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f44a657f8b9a1d318b4567"),
  // other fields
  "ligaments": [
    [
      {
        "data": "dia",
        "order": 0
      },
      {
        "data": "hub",
        "order": 1
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "data": "pcd",
        "order": 0
      },
      {
        "data": "width",
        "order": 1
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I need to find all entries in which the `ligaments` field contains `data: 'parameter'` attribute. How do I make such a query?

Comment: Try `db.collection.find({ ligaments.data : 'parameter'})`  ?

Comment: Although mongodb is schemaless, this doesn't mean you don't need to think about your schema.

Comment: Ok, I dont correct asked, I need find all document with one of ligament field items contains only "pcd" and "width" data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search within nested arrays, you can do so by using the `$elemMatch` operator:

```
//returns all the documents that have data equal to 'pcd' or 'width'
db.collection.find({ligaments: {$elemMatch: {$elemMatch: { data: {$in: ['pcd', 'width']}}}}});
```

If you want to specify a user-defined parameter, you can do so my customizing the query:

```
//returns all the documents that have data equal to 'parameter'
db.collection.find({ligaments: {$elemMatch: {$elemMatch: { data: 'parameter'}}}});
```

Comment: This query returns no results

Comment: @i.paramonov I presume you have changed the collection in my query with your actual collection? I have tried running this query and it works just fine.

Comment: I cant find by this query, i use mongodb 2.6.6 version. And query returns zero results

Comment: @i.paramonov Could you please paste here the exact query that you are running? If you copy paste my above query, it will not work as the collection name differs.

Comment: @i.paramonov I have tried this query using MongoDB 2.6.5 and it works just as intended. Make sure that you do not simply copy paste this query - you need to replace collection in db.collection.find with your collection name.

Comment: I tried this query in rockmongo as `ligaments: { $elemMatch: {
        $elemMatch: {
            data: 'parameter'
        }
    } }` and rockmongo returns "No records is found."

Comment: I have only tested it in the mongo shell on a collection with your document structure and it works. Can you also try to run it from the mongo shell?

Comment: Hm, I dont understand, example from my question works fine, but this example
`{
  _id: ObjectId("54f44a657f8b9a1d318b4567"),
  location: { $ref: "Location", $id: "category_page", $db: "test" },
  category: { $ref: "Category", $id: ObjectId("5433b409e31701ed7be1aa6e"), $db: "test" },
  "ligaments": [
    [
      { data: "{\"id\":\"5433b4e6e317011a0564c099\",\"text\":\"Wheels diametr\",\"placeholder\":\"diametr\"}", order: 0 },
      { data: "{\"id\":\"5433b4e6e317011a0564c09b\",\"text\":\"DIA\",\"placeholder\":\"dia\"}", order: 1 }
    ]
  ]
}` dont work

Comment: Thanks, Vlad, your query works fine, this is a rockmongo bug, she show me not correct json object, him contains each ligaments with string key ("0", "1"...) thanks again

Comment: But i dont understand, how i can find document by two data attributes in one ligament

Answer (score 0):

First your document structure was to complicated  but, still if you want find out your output then try below script

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$ligaments"
}, {
    "$unwind": "$ligaments"
}, {
    "$match": {
    "ligaments.data": {
        "$in": ["pcd", "width"]
    }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "ligaments": "$ligaments"
    }
})
```